# How to use an array parameter in Facebook Query request in Android.

Tags: java, android, facebook-fql

Right now I am using Android's Bundle to create requests for Facebook Query Language

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("method", "fql.query");
params.putString("query", "SELECT * FROM * WHERE source_id = *");
mAsyncRunner.request(params, new ExampleRequestListener());
```

From PHP examples I have seen arrays of user IDs sent as a parameter for a query, but how can I add an array to this bundle to make the request from Java for an Android application?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the query you send to FQL has little to do with the fact that you are using Bundle, Android and Java - the magic will happen in the FQL query itself.

The canonical example for an FQL query on multiple UIDs seems to go something like this:

```
$fql = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";
```

or from fql multiquery documentation:

```
"query1":"SELECT uid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE eid=12345678"
"query2":"SELECT name, url, pic FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT uid FROM #query1)"
```

So for your case I would modify the line with the query. I also notice that you have

```
SELECT * FROM *
```

in that line. are you sure you don't want to choose a table?
For instance:

```
params.putString("query", "SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid in [YOUR SOURCE LIST]);
```